# Aiogram3 Bot New Chat Member Handler

Tags: python, bots, aiogram

I've been trying to make a greeting message to a new chat member, but can't quite wrap my head around it.

Right now I have a separate router that looks like:

```
from aiogram import F, Router, Bot
from aiogram.filters.chat_member_updated import \
    ChatMemberUpdatedFilter, IS_NOT_MEMBER, MEMBER, ADMINISTRATOR
from aiogram.types import ChatMemberUpdated


new_member_router = Router()

@new_member_router.chat_member(
    ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(
        member_status_changed=IS_NOT_MEMBER >> MEMBER
    )
)

async def new_member(event: ChatMemberUpdated, bot: Bot):
        chat_info = await bot.get_chat(event.chat.id)
        await bot.send_message(chat_info, f"Hi!",
                    parse_mode="HTML")
```

But the event is still not handled.
The router is included in main.py.

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried the method from my Telebot Bot but got the message that I've used an outdated filter and should use F.{something} now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it after quite some time.

```
from aiogram import F, Router, Bot
from aiogram.filters import IS_MEMBER, IS_NOT_MEMBER, ChatMemberUpdatedFilter
from aiogram.types import ChatMemberUpdated


new_member_router = Router()

@new_member_router.chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(IS_NOT_MEMBER >> IS_MEMBER))
async def new_member(event: ChatMemberUpdated, bot: Bot):
        
        await event.answer(f"<b>Hi, {event.new_chat_member.user.first_name}!</b>",
                    parse_mode="HTML")
```

But you will probably need to enable getting chat_member updates.
I'm using webhooks so it's done like that:

```
async def on_startup(bot: Bot) -> None:
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{BASE_WEBHOOK_URL}{WEBHOOK_PATH}", 
                          secret_token=WEBHOOK_SECRET,
                          allowed_updates=["message", "chat_member"])
```

Hope that will help someone!